Vercel CLI installation with npm not working - vercel command not found
I installed the Vercel CLI using npm with the following command:
npm install -g vercel

However, when I try to run the vercel command, I get the error:
zsh: command not found: vercel

I’ve tried the following troubleshooting steps:
I confirmed that Vercel is installed globally by running npm list -g --depth=0
opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/23.2.0_1/lib
├── corepack@0.29.4
└── vercel@39.1.1

, and the output includes vercel@39.1.1.
I checked the global npm path using npm config get prefix and found it to be /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/23.2.0_1.
I added the global bin directory (/opt/homebrew/bin) to my PATH in my ~/.zshrc file and reloaded the terminal.
Despite these steps, the vercel command is still not found.
I’ve also tried running the which vercel command, but it returns nothing.
Can anyone suggest what else I can try to resolve this issue and make the vercel command work properly on my machine?
System Info:
macOS (installed via Homebrew)
Node.js version: 23.2.0
npm version: [Insert npm version here]
Thank you for your help!

I think you can install vercel-cli by brew, so get rid of the node dependency.
