Vercel CLI installation with npm not working - vercel command not found
I installed the Vercel CLI using npm with the following command:
npm install -g vercel

However, when I try to run the vercel command, I get the error:
vercel --version
zsh: command not found: vercel

’ve tried the following troubleshooting steps:
I confirmed that Vercel is installed globally by running npm list -g --depth=0
npm list -g --depth=0
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/23.2.0_1/lib
├── corepack@0.29.4
└── vercel@39.1.1

, and the output includes vercel@39.1.1.
I’ve also tried running the which vercel command
which vercel
vercel not found

, but it returns nothing.
System Info:
macOS
Node.js version: 23.2.0 (installed via Homebrew)
npm version: 9.5.0

Thanks For Help.


You already asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79225494/vercel-cli-installation-with-npm-not-working-vercel-command-not-found, Please close this.

This question is similar to: Vercel CLI installation with npm not working - vercel command not found. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is specific to Node installation. The problem suggests that path environment variable for npm binaries is misconfigured. Node can be reinstalled to fix this, either from the installer or version manager (nvm or fnm). FWIW odd Node versions shouldn't be used without a reason, the latest even version is 22.
You can use commands globally without installing them like npx vercel, this is often a preferable way to use them.
